# How does correct gamma color on external screen? Linux laptop

Tags: hardware, laptop, screen

I have got a laptop and i would like to correct gamma color on my **external** screen.

My system: *Laptop, VGA port, Linux, Ubuntu.*

In option System->Preferences->Monitor i turn off my laptop's screen.

But bash-command  `xgamma -gamma 5` does not any effect. BTW on laptop is (if it will turn on) too.

**How can i get it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adjusting it with the xrandr command.

First find your device name by entering:

```
xrandr
```

There's an output line like:

```
LVDS connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 367mm x 230mm
```

You'll have to determine which choice is your external monitor.

The enter a command like (substituting for your device LVDS):

```
xrandr --output LVDS --prop --verbose --gamma 1.0:1.0:1.5
```

experiment with value, until you like the results. The numbesr must be floating point and they stand for red:green:blue.

The driver shouldn't matter.

See [this man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xrandr.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one screen, you have to select the one you want `xgamma` to target. Check your screens with `echo $DISPLAY`. The result for my single screen is `:0.0`. So if I wanted to target my screen I would use `:0.0` (even though with one screen it is unnecessary), and thus enter the following: `xgamma -display :0.0 -gamma 1.2`.

So with this information in mind, turn off your laptop screen, simply find what display number your external screen is using with `echo $DISPLAY` , and include that in the `xgamma` command that I have given above.

If that does not solve it, and if you are running proprietary drivers from Nvidia or AMD, you may need to look at the settings and options of those devices rather than xgamma.

Comment: Thank you my friend. But when i turn off laptop screen **$DISPLAY** is **":0.0"** too :( Other combination (from my mind) does not work too. And i can not  target **xgamma** correct. What is wrong?

Comment: Well, yes when there is only one screen $DISPLAY will be :0.0, so with the laptop screen off, did you try xgamma -display :0.0 -gamma 1.2 If that doesn't work you may have to look at some of the settings for your graphic drivers-are you using proprietary ones?

Comment: Thank you. $DISPLAY is **":0.0"** in both cases (laptop & external is on and latop is off & external is on). Command **"xgamma -display :0.0 -gamma 1.2"** does not effect at all. My hardware is Lenovo x201 with video adapter "Intel GMA HD". Its driver goes from Ubuntu 10.10. How can i know the correct address of my external screen and correct its gamma? ;/

Comment: Correct text: Command **"xgamma -display :0.0 -gamma 1.2"** does not effect at last case. But at first case is work obviously.

Comment: If it was an Nvidia or AMD card I would say look at the driver settings, but with it being an Intel device I'm not sure what else we could try beyond experimenting with the display values.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this. PS Am i right understanding that address of external display should be other then **:0.0** ? E.g. **:0.1** or **:1**

Comment: Yes, you could try :0.1 or :1.1, and perhaps have a look in your xorg.0.log in gnome-system-log for clues

Comment: Ok! Mik, Thank you again. Dont you offend if i dont close this question?.. :)

Comment: That's fine- hope you get it sorted out.