# How to solve graphics driver problem which changes a little the colors in any program just on the external monitor?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

I have an external monitor which changes the nuance of blue to something more violet, in all programs (image comparison below). (Screenshots do not have this problem.)

The monitor works well with Windows (I dual-boot with Windows 10). [This](https://www.dell.com/support/home/ro/ro/robsdt1/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3537/drivers) is my laptop (purchased in 2013 or 2014).

I tried to change the gamma with `xrandr` ([based on this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/175133/29733)) but it seems to not be related to gamma.

I remember I used Ubuntu a few years ago and it did not have any problem like this (with the same external monitor!).

The laptop screen shows the image well.

I use the latest version of Ubuntu as of this writing, 19.10. The Ubuntu installation is 16 days old and the problem was there from the start of this installation.

How can I make the external monitor display colors well?

## Images

### Original picture

[image: original picture]

### External monitor photo

[image: external monitor]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the images in the question is smaller than the difference between the same web page opened in Firefox and in Google Chrome, which was the main problem. I switched from Google Chrome to Firefox because in Firefox the main problem does not exist.